# NiFi: QueryElasticSearchHTTP result to attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

Im using `QueryElasticSearchHTTP` processor to query an index in ES.
Im able to retrieve the content as flowfile-content but not as flowfile-attributes.
`es.result` values are empty.
The url produced in `es.query.url` also works fine when I manually query it from the browser.

Here is my QueryElasticSearchHTTP config and the result:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the form of the result? any example?

Comment: It's json. I see empty values in the es.result.*